# Kubernetes (k3s) posts stuck in creation

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I have a K3S Kubernetes cluster. 
All my pods get stuck in the containerCr

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: The error is already clearly visible in the log though? Some certificate cannot be validated. Are you on a corporate network?

Comment: yes on a cooperate network, so do you recon its the proxy modifying the certificate and that is what is causing the issue?

Comment: Yes. You can easily check with your web browser. Go to any HTTPS site (you’re looking at one) and investigate the certificate chain.

Comment: So i have checked via the browser and the certificates are being modified. How can i get kubernetes to ignore the certificates?
ps
I have set up all the proxy config in /etc/enviroment

Answer (score 0):

IMHO ignoring the certificate would be very dangerous. A hacker could get your K8S to run containers he forged. Either:

- you add your corporate root certs to K8S
- your corporate IT has a way to bypass the proxy in some cases (or at least make it transparent to HTTPS traffic)
- (IMHO the best solution) you make your own local image registry (this isn't that difficult) with the images you need.